# Differentiability at removable and nonremovable discontinuities

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Is a function differentiable at a removable discontinuity? Is it differentiable at a nonremovable discontinuity?

Comment: Renewable discontinuity?

Comment: Do you possibly mean "removable" discontinuity?

Comment: I assume it is aboute removable and nonremovable discontinuities ...

Comment: If you mean removable, then no, and no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{x^2}{|x|}$ is defined and continuous for all $x\ne 0$, and equals $|x|$ there, hence has a *removable* discontinuity at $x=0$. But the continuation function  $x\mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable. (Note that the *original* function is not differentiable or continuous there simply cause it is not even defined there).

If the discontinuity is nonremovable, then the function is certainly not differentiable there. After all, a differentiable function is also continuous.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense